# excel locking/unlocking cells not working with VBA that hides rows

Tags: vba, excel, locking, hide

I am very new to VBA, and trying to do what i can.

I have a workbook for different projects and the staff working on those projects,
I have it so that when a staff members name is next to a project on the overview sheet, 
The rows associated with that project are unhidden on their personal sheet,
What I want is only a few blocks of cells, within the rows of each project to have text able to be entered into them (so unlocked, with the rest locked), unfortunately when I try to do this, it stuffs up how the project rows display.
Can anyone give me an idea how I can do this or why this is happening?

Here are the blocks I want unlocked in the sheet (sorted by project, so hidden/ shown together):
(B16:g27, i16: j28, B29:G29)
(B34:g45, i34: j46, B47:G47)
(B52:g63, i52: j64, B65:G65)
(B70:g81, i70: j82, B83:G83)
(B88:g99, i88: j100, B101:G101)
(B106:117, i106: j117, B119:G119)

any help would be hugely appreciated, I have looked through some forums and I cannot seem to find anything this specific, unless i am searching for the wrong search terms...

Here is my VBA for showing and hiding project rows:

```
`Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim i As Long, StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long

StartRow = 13
EndRow = 29

For i = 6 To 11
    If UCase(Range("C" & i).Value) = "NO" Then
        Rows(StartRow & ":" & EndRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(StartRow & ":" & EndRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    StartRow = StartRow + 18
    EndRow = EndRow + 18
Next i

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the cells you want to be unlocked by selecting them in the sheet and then right click on the selection --> Format cells... --> Tab Protection and there unmark the check box Locked.

Then protect your sheet selecting Review in the ribbon and Protect Sheet. Or programatically `Sheets("name_of_sheet").Protect "your_password"`. The previous selected cells will remain unlocked.

Comment: Thanks @weilah, however I have tried this and it results in the same problem I am experiencing, it stops hiding inactive projects and debugger comes up.
This is the line highlighted by the debugger:
    
     Rows(StartRow & ":" & EndRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False